# converting a php script to use microsoft sql from mysql

Tags: mysql, asp.net, database

I have a php script which uses mysql but i am running Microsoft SQL 2012(where I created a web app). . How do I go about changing the script to use Microsoft SQL. I have included the code below. I'm hoping its not too difficult. Any help would be greatly appreciated.this is used to connect a mobile app to the database.

```
 <?php



 //DATABASE DETAILS//
  $DB_ADDRESS="";
  $DB_USER="";
  $DB_PASS="";
  $DB_NAME="";

 //SETTINGS//
 //This code is something you set in the APP so random people cant use it.
  $SQLKEY="randomkey";


 //these are just in case setting headers forcing it to always expire
  header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');

  error_log(print_r($_POST,TRUE));

  if( isset($_POST['query']) && isset($_POST['key']) ){  
  //2014/02/18: set content type to CSV 
  header('Content-type: text/csv');

   if($_POST['key']==$SQLKEY){          //validate the SQL key
   $query=urldecode($_POST['query']);
   if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  {  
    $query=stripslashes($query);
  }
   $link = mysql_connect($DB_ADDRESS,$DB_USER,$DB_PASS);//connect ot the MYSQL database
   mysql_select_db($DB_NAME,$link);                          //connect to the right DB
    if($link){
  $result=mysql_query($query); //runs the posted query (NO PROTECTION FROM INJECTION)
  if($result){
    if (strlen(stristr($query,"SELECT"))>0) {    //tests if its a select statemnet
  $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);//collects the rows & writes out a header row
      $headers = array();
      for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
        $headers[] = mysql_field_name($result , $i);
      }
      $outstream = fopen("php://temp", 'r+');//opens up a temp stream to hold the data
      fputcsv($outstream, $headers, ',', '"');
      while ($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)){
        fputcsv($outstream, $row, ',', '"');
      }
      rewind($outstream);
      fpassthru($outstream);
      fclose($outstream);
      // echo $csv; //writes out csv data back to the client
    } else {
      header("HTTP/1.0 201 Rows");
      echo "AFFECTED ROWS: ".mysql_affected_rows($link); 
    }
    } else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");      //send back a bad request error
    echo mysql_errno($link).": ".mysql_error($link);     
    }
     mysql_close($link);      //close the DB
    } else {
   header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
   echo "ERROR Database Connection Failed";  //reports a DB connection failure
   }
  } else {
   header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
   echo "Bad Request";       //reports if the code is bad/
  }
   } else {
    header("HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request");
    echo "Bad Request";
   }
   ?>
```

Comment: the code is up now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing mysql to mysqli. Example: mysqli_connect